# Java byte array comparison

Tags: java, hadoop, byte

I am reading the source code of hadoop, but int the

> org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator
>   has a function:

```
public static int compareBytes(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1,
                             byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
int end1 = s1 + l1;
int end2 = s2 + l2;
for (int i = s1, j = s2; i < end1 && j < end2; i++, j++) {
  int a = (b1[i] & 0xff);
  int b = (b2[j] & 0xff);
  if (a != b) {
    return a - b;
  }
}
return l1 - l2;
}
```

and my question is Why do we need a variable a and b here?Why not direct comparison?

Comment: `a` and `b` are read twice, so I guess to reduce code duplication.

Comment: thank you and I mean why use `& 0xff`

Comment: The 0xff changes the ordering. It treats bytes as being in the range 0-255 rather than -128 to 127

Comment: To convert -128 to 127 byte range to 0-255